# функция transform css

Tags: css

Есть вот такой пример, который поворачивает блок прямоугольный

```css
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}

 .flip-container:hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 320px;
 height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.front {
 background: green;
 z-index: 2;
}

.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 background: red;
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не могу найти ответы, чтобы точнее понять его действие.

- perspective: 1000; - Зачем он нужен? как бы я не изменял его значение, ничего ровным счетом не меняется.
- Второй блок при наведении заставляет див с обоими блоками развернуться на 180 градусов, далее блок устанавливает ширину и высоту, но что делает 4 блок?
  transition - плавность перехода, а вот transform-style как работает не понятно вообще. если заменить значение на flat, то видно будет только зеленый блок. Почему? Как это работает?
- backface-visibility: hidden; Это какая-то специфическая штука для preserve-3d? ПО логике вроде прячет заднюю часть блока. Но все равно трудно понять.
- И зачем нам z-index? Если есть backface-visibility: hidden?
  Очень прошу помочь разобраться, моих знаний пока не хватает на элементарные вещи =)

Comment: А вы читали документацию к этим свойствам?

Comment: читал, но видимо тупой слишком, чтобы понять толком. особенно почему perspective не работает

Comment: а ты сделай perspective:300px; и увидишь как заработает

Comment: ну дак само собой я это делал))) но эффекта 0, отсюда и непонятки

Comment: @PaulWall  
пиши на почту- попробую объяснить - здесь подобные вопросы удаляют обычно